# CSS animations in SVG on Android Chrome broken - origin issue

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, svg

Recent update on Android Chrome (I don't know about other platforms) came with a bug I suppose. The transform origin is miscalculated when CSS animation is in use. I have prepared the example:

http://bigred80.amike.pl/panelbug.svg

On other browsers, the two squares stay in place, one is scaled. On Android Chrome 89.0.4389.86 the green square is flying from one corner to the other. Same issue shows up in multiple scenarios, all are related to CSS animations.

I'm creating complex applications using SVG files for over 6 years. CSS animations are widely used in these applications and this issue spoils nearly all my work.

I tried workaround it using transform-origin property but sometimes it is almost impossible. In SVG, objects are encapsulated in multiple groups and which of them can have it's own transforms static or animated.

One important note: Android 9. I have tried on 10 and no issue.

Any idea?

Comment: I see it ok . Version  89.0.4389 (PC, not android)

Comment: Report the bugs in Chrome to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)